# Pyqt QtCore.QTimer() .timeout.connect(self.function) error [missing 1 required positional argument: 'Form']

Tags: python, timer, pyqt5, qtcore, qtimer

As part of a function inside a python script of a PyQt5 Gui i have the following code:

```
def link_info(self, Form):
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.stop
    self.ip=self.lineEdit_ip.text()
    self.port=int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
    self.function(Form)
    print('here')
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.function)
    self.timer.start(5000)
```

I am getting the error:

> function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Form'

When I change the code to:

```
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.function(Form))
```

I get the error:

> argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use either `lambda: self.function(Form)` or `functools.partial(self.function, Form)` to get a callable which doesn't require an argument, but still can be called at a later time by QTimer.